# Byte not showing addition result in Java

Tags: java, variables, byte, addition

Why am I not getting the output since `byte` value is from -128 to 127 and the result is 30 ?

```
class test15 {          
   public static void main(String ...s) {
      byte a = 10;
      byte b = 20;
      byte c = a+b;
      System.out.println(c);
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no instruction set to perform operation on a `byte` type. Rather the instruction set for `int` type is used for the operation on `boolean`, `byte`, `char`, and `short` types.`http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1`
Also
A data type of higher size (occupying more memory) cannot be assigned to a data type of lower size. This is not done implicitly by the JVM and requires explicit casting; a casting operation to be performed by the programmer

The result will be an Integer. For this you must do

```
byte a = 10;
byte b = 20;
byte c = (byte) (a + b); //u will have to typecast int to byte 

System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: i know the concept of typecast but what i am not able to understand is since byte value is from -128 to 127 value of C which is 30 also falls under it then why error ?

Comment: Because that's how the Java Virtual Machine is designed. There is no instruction set to perform operation on a byte type. Rather the instruction set for int type is used for the operation on boolean, byte, char, and short types.

Comment: Are you sure that `short` has no addition operator? I remember that `short+short` worked on Java7, but don't have Java7 on my PC here

Comment: yes u can check here  JVM Spec - Section 2.11.1:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This answer is spot on (though I recommend adding the JVM Spec link to the main text of the answer rather than leave it languishing in the comments section).

Comment: @kirti `byte c = (byte)(a + b)`; after conversion, this expression will look like this `byte c = 30` where 30 is of type byte. But then, as the numeric promotion states that all byte, short and char literals are converted to int, this byte 30 would be promoted to int 30. So in this sense, the compiler should still give an error but it doesn't. Why?

Answer (score 5):

**CompileTime vs RunTime**

a,b are bytes and bytes doesn't have addition operator. At run time, since a,b are not final and integer addition takes place which result is an `int`. And you are trying to assign it to a byte. Which results a compilation error.

```
byte c = (byte)a+b;
```

And as a side note. try to change your code as

```
 final byte a = 10;
 final byte b = 20;
 byte c = a + b;
```

That compiles fine because of narrowing conversion and it is possible, if all the operands are constant values in an expression.

Comment: Since Java 8, it is enough when they are effectively final, and they are in the OP's code

Comment: @msrd0 [Yes, I agree with you.](http://codeinventions.blogspot.in/2014/07/difference-between-final-and.html)

Answer (score 2):

You must cast to `byte`. Since `a` and `b` are of type byte, Java will convert them to an `int`, and then the result is an `int`.

```
byte c = (byte) (a+b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Compile time error, if I change this

```
byte c = a + b;
```

to

```
byte c = (byte) (a + b);
```

I get the output

```
30
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
byte c = a + b;
```

to

```
byte c = (byte)(a + b);
```

It works for me.

Comment: i know the concept of typecast but what i am not able to understand is since byte value is from -128 to 127 value of C which is 30 also falls under it then why error ?

Comment: because byte hasn't got additional operator, like sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ said. His solution is better than mine, use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Java converts the result of arithmetic operations to `int` type by default. Try this:

```
public static void main(String... s)
{

    byte a = 10;
    byte b = 20;
    byte c = (byte) (a + b);

System.out.println(c);
}
```

That `(byte)` changes the int value returned by (a+b) into a byte value. Normally, this cannot be done, as the range of int is much greater than the range of byte, so a loss of precision would occur. Using casting forces the conversion, regardless of precision.

Comment: so as per your saying "Java converts the result of arithmetic operations to int type by default" 

is for all variables like long, float, short ?? or just in case of byte ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's whats happening

```
byte a = 10;
```

variable a of byte type created 10 assigned to it.

```
byte b = 20;
```

variable b of byte type created 10 assigned to it.

```
byte c = a+b;
```

`a+b` is automatically promoted to integer, since now result of summation is integer you cannot assign integer to byte.